# How to display the user-selected items from a ListBox in a MessageBox? - C# Windows Forms .NET

Tags: c#, forms, menu, listbox, menustrip

Like the title says, I am trying to display the items a user selects from a ListBox in a MessageBox. This MessageBox is supposed to be part of a menu strip. I was wondering if anyone might be able to help me with this. Here is the related code:

```
private void displaySelectionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// this is where the message box is supposed to be 
}

if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Fudge")
{
cost +=6;
listBox1.Items.Add("Fudge");
textBox1.Text = cost.ToString("C");
}
if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Caramel")
{
cost +=4;
listBox1.Items.Add("Caramel");
textBox1.Text = cost.ToString("C");
}
```

**Unsuccessful Attempts of Coding this**

```
private void displaySelectionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object 
sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string display = (listBox1.SelectedItems.ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < display.Length; i++
        {
        MessageBox.Show(display)
        }
}

private void displaySelectionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object 
sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItems.ToString());
         }

 private void displaySelectionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object 
 sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List <string> display = new List <string>();
        string str = null;
        foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            display.Add(item.ToString());
            str += item + "\r\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

I have a much greater number of methods dealing with the various options the user can choose, but they appear repetitive enough that most of them can be omitted. Please let me know if these methods are insufficient for my question.

So if both Fudge and Caramel are selected, I would like both of these items to appear in a message box when "Display Selection" on the ToolStripMenu is selected.

I attempted a wide variety of solutions over the past few hours, but none of them were helpful. I am repeatedly getting "System.Windows.Forms.ListBox" as the output in the message box, as opposed to the selected items.

Comment: Can you share the code which gives you `"System.Windows.Forms.ListBox"` output?

Comment: Little confused by your question. I don't have any code under listBox1 in Form1.cs. In Form1.Designer.cs I have the computer-generated this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox(); and private System.Windows.Forms.Listbox listbox1; .

Comment: listBox1 is completely devoid of any items until it is populated by whatever the user selects, with these items appearing instantaneously after they are selected. For the project I am trying to do, it is also not required for me to code for the user unchecking items.

Comment: `I am repeatedly getting "System.Windows.Forms.ListBox" as the output in the message box` what does this mean? What code causes this?

Comment: Ah I see. It is from my failed coding in the displaySelection method. I experimented with over ten variations at this point, would you like me to post some examples?

Comment: `Ah I see. It is from my failed coding in the displaySelection method` can you share that code in the question?

Comment: Just added a couple examples of my failed attempts.

Comment: Do you want a listbox and not just display a list of the selected items? You can create a string that is a list and pass it to the messageBox. Would this work? I ask because of this: `MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItems.ToString());`

Comment: II already have a dynamic listbox that works, but I have to also have the items of that listbox be displayed in a MessageBox. How could I pass a string that is a list to the MessageBox? That sounds viable.

Comment: @ronalddonaldronald the last snippet of `displaySelectionToolStripMenuItem_Click` looks good to me. Are you not getting expected result in that?

Comment: Yep. Still can't find a way to get the correct result.